# Autostart with AutostartCondition

Tags: linux, autostart

I want to run some program at the certain condition.

So I have created .desktop file and put it int /etc/xdg/autostart.

Here desktop file is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=System Tray
Exec=/opt/testApp
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
NoDisplay=true
AutostartCondition=GSettings com.test testVal
X-GNOME-AutoRestart=true
```

And I have made a custom key with gsettings for a condition and compiled the schemas.

I confirm if the schema works, it works.

```
$> gsettings set com.test testVal true
$> gsettings get com.test testVal
```

I typed the command above, and got "true".

However the Application I registered as Autostart doesn't run.

Do I have to restart or logoff for a test?

Is there a way to test autostart without reboot or logoff?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://askubuntu.com/questions/566838/autostart-with-autostartcondition and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176542/autostart-with-autostartcondition